# Complicated transformation pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Assume that I have the following data set

```
table = [[datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1), 1, 0.5],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 27), 1, 0.5],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 31), 1, 0.5],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 1), 1, 2],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 3), 1, 2],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 15), 1, 2], 
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 28), 1, 2],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 1), 1, 3],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 17), 1, 3],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 31), 1, 3]]

df = pd.DataFrame(table, columns=['Date', 'Id', 'Value'])
```

Now, I'd like to find the last value of each month, move it monthwise to the values of the next month, and finally take the cumulative product of these values. Doing this procedure for the above data should result in (performing each step):

1. Finding the last entry of each month and moving them monthwise would result in

   ```
               Date       Id   Value  Temp
            0 2015-01-01   1    0.5    NaN
            1 2015-01-27   1    0.5    NaN
            2 2015-01-31   1    0.5    NaN
            3 2015-02-01   1    2.0    0.5
            4 2015-02-03   1    2.0    0.5
            5 2015-02-15   1    2.0    0.5
            6 2015-02-28   1    2.0    0.5
            7 2015-03-01   1    3.0    2.0
            8 2015-03-17   1    3.0    2.0
            9 2015-03-31   1    3.0    2.0
   ```
2. Filling the `NaN`'s with `1`, taking the cumulative product, and dropping `temp` would result in

   ```
                Date      Id   Value  Result
            0 2015-01-01   1    0.5     1
            1 2015-01-27   1    0.5     1
            2 2015-01-31   1    0.5     1
            3 2015-02-01   1    2.0    0.5
            4 2015-02-03   1    2.0    0.5
            5 2015-02-15   1    2.0    0.5
            6 2015-02-28   1    2.0    0.5
            7 2015-03-01   1    3.0    1.0
            8 2015-03-17   1    3.0    1.0
            9 2015-03-31   1    3.0    1.0
   ```

I hope that this is clear enough. And if anyone wonders why on earth I'd like to do this is because I've got MTD-data, and it needs to be resampled. Thanks, Tingis.

**edit**
The number of entries per month are "random", as in they can either be as long as the month or shorter (business data...)

Comment: Do you always have two entries per month? Because you could use `Series.shift(2)` in that case.

Comment: No, sorry, they're always as long as the month, I was a bit unclear on that, sorry! But thanks for the quick reply

Comment: Could you add this to your example, because I am not sure how you want to deal with different values during the same month and variable length months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code does not assume that you have only two rows for each month. The idea is that do the group-wise calculation first, and then populate some NaN using `.reindex()` and fill those NaNs using backward fill as we've got the value for the very last entry of each month.

```
# your data
# ==================================
import pandas as pd
import datetime

table = [[datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1), 1, 0.5],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 31), 1, 0.5],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 1), 1, 2], 
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 28), 1, 2],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 1), 1, 3],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 31), 1, 3]]

df = pd.DataFrame(table, columns=['Date', 'Id', 'Value'])

# better to set Date column to index
df = df.set_index('Date')
print(df)

            Id  Value
Date                 
2015-01-01   1    0.5
2015-01-31   1    0.5
2015-02-01   1    2.0
2015-02-28   1    2.0
2015-03-01   1    3.0
2015-03-31   1    3.0

# processing
# =================================================
# get last entry from each month
df_temp = df.groupby(lambda idx: idx.month).tail(1)
# do the cumprod, reindex to have the same index as original df, backward fill
df['Result'] = df_temp['Value'].shift(1).fillna(1).cumprod().reindex(df.index).fillna(method='bfill')

print(df)

            Id  Value  Result
Date                         
2015-01-01   1    0.5     1.0
2015-01-31   1    0.5     1.0
2015-02-01   1    2.0     0.5
2015-02-28   1    2.0     0.5
2015-03-01   1    3.0     1.0
2015-03-31   1    3.0     1.0
```

For the follow-ups question:

```
# your data
# ==================================
import pandas as pd
import datetime

table = [[datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1), 1, 0.5],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 27), 1, 0.5],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 31), 1, 0.5],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 1), 1, 2],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 3), 1, 2],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 15), 1, 2], 
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 2, 28), 1, 2],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 1), 1, 3],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 17), 1, 3],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 31), 1, 3]]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(table, columns=['Date', 'Id', 'Value'])
df2 = df1.copy()
df2.Id = 2

df = df1.append(df2)
# better to set Date column to index
df = df.set_index('Date')

print(df)


            Id  Value
Date                 
2015-01-01   1    0.5
2015-01-27   1    0.5
2015-01-31   1    0.5
2015-02-01   1    2.0
2015-02-03   1    2.0
2015-02-15   1    2.0
2015-02-28   1    2.0
2015-03-01   1    3.0
2015-03-17   1    3.0
2015-03-31   1    3.0
2015-01-01   2    0.5
2015-01-27   2    0.5
2015-01-31   2    0.5
2015-02-01   2    2.0
2015-02-03   2    2.0
2015-02-15   2    2.0
2015-02-28   2    2.0
2015-03-01   2    3.0
2015-03-17   2    3.0
2015-03-31   2    3.0

def my_func(group):
    # get last entry from each month
    df_temp = group.groupby(lambda idx: idx.month).tail(1)
    # do the cumprod, reindex to have the same index as original df
    group['Result'] = df_temp['Value'].shift(1).fillna(1).cumprod().reindex(group.index).fillna(method='bfill')
    return group

df.groupby('Id').apply(my_func)



            Id  Value  Result
Date                         
2015-01-01   1    0.5     1.0
2015-01-27   1    0.5     1.0
2015-01-31   1    0.5     1.0
2015-02-01   1    2.0     0.5
2015-02-03   1    2.0     0.5
2015-02-15   1    2.0     0.5
2015-02-28   1    2.0     0.5
2015-03-01   1    3.0     1.0
2015-03-17   1    3.0     1.0
2015-03-31   1    3.0     1.0
2015-01-01   2    0.5     1.0
2015-01-27   2    0.5     1.0
2015-01-31   2    0.5     1.0
2015-02-01   2    2.0     0.5
2015-02-03   2    2.0     0.5
2015-02-15   2    2.0     0.5
2015-02-28   2    2.0     0.5
2015-03-01   2    3.0     1.0
2015-03-17   2    3.0     1.0
2015-03-31   2    3.0     1.0
```

Comment: Btw, is there anyway to include such that they are also grouped on `Id`? That is if there are multiple `Id`'s?

Comment: @Tingiskhan Yes, it's possible. You just need to first groupby `Id` and then move all the processing into an apply function `my_func`. I've updated the code. Please have a look.

Comment: Wow, are you a wizard or something?